Whom did Rashi call "oker harim"
In Bava Kamma 109b Rashi (s.v. lamed-alef, in the middle of the page) brings an alternative explanation in the name of "oker harim." Do we have any clue who he meant by that? Artscroll does not say. And Tosafot bring the same perush but do not attribute it to anyone in particular.

As noted by Shmosel in a comment, Prof Shamma Friedman has a Hebrew article entitled פירושי רש”י למסכתות התלמוד (available for download as article 113 on his webpage).
In the article, he suggests that Oker Harim refers to Rashi's teacher, R. Yaakov b. Yakar, basing himself on some wordplay in his name: יעקוב בן יקר.
